# What does port number14443 signify?

Tags: internet, port, network-traffic

In an internet traffic measurement it is seen that port 14443 carries a large amount of traffic. What exactly is this port? and what can be the explanation?

Comment: Does not seem like a programming question.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like a system administration question either.

Comment: My guess is just a creative alternate https port.  Definitely off-topic, though.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [BRU backup software (per Internet Storm Center)](http://isc.sans.edu/port.html?port=14443), or [misbehaving SonicPoint wireless access points](http://steveballantyne.blogspot.com/2007/01/sonicpoints-eat-udp-14443-connections.html).

Answer (score 1):

Is that port seen from the client side? If so, what server side port is in use? My guess is that's an ephemeral port being used on the client side to connect to a well known port on the server (80, 25, etc).